# Need to find duplicate records for records which exist after a specified date

Tags: db2, db2-400

My requirement is two-fold, I have a huge source table with millions of records, and I need to get records after a cut-off date and then find if there are any relating records with the same metadata and group them. The relating records could be from a date before the cut-off date.
Original Table

---

```
Account Company  Ledger P01   P02---P12              Date
1000     XYZ      XX     0   20                    07/06/18
2000     XYZ      XX     0   30                    07/06/18
1000     XYZ      XX     10  30                    07/01/18
3000      XYZ     XX     20  50                    06/05/18
Cutoff date =  07/05/18
Expected result
Account Company           Ledger      P01 P02---P12 
1000       XYZ             XX         10   50  
2000      XYZ              XX          0   30
```

Comment: Can you please add more clarification to this question?  How do you want to group them?  Are you summing up fields P01 and P02?  I suspect you can handle this with a common table expression SQL query fairly easily but it's hard to say without clarification.

Comment: Yeah, I want to sum up records with similar metadata in this case: Account, Company and Ledger and summed up values for P01 and P02. I have tried using Select * from xyz , abc where xyz.Date> abc.Cutoff_Date having count(*)>1

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it on iSeries

```
SELECT account, company, ledger, sum(P01) , sum(P02) 
from test_1 t
where exists (select 1 from test_1 
               where date1 > '2018-07-05' 
                 and account =  t.account 
                 and company = t.company 
                 and ledger = t.ledger)
group by account, company, ledger
```

Due to your sparse descrption the grouping columns or column names may need some adjustment

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should get you want you want.

```
with MYDATA as (
    select distinct Account as Act, Company as Cmp, Ledger as Ldgr
    from MYTABLE
    where Date > Cutoff_Date)
select Account, Company, Ledger, sum(P01), sum(P02)
from MYTABLE join MYDATA
    on Account = Act and Company = Cmp and Ledger = Ldgr
group by Account, Company, Ledger
```